# Find the longest word in stringLongestWord(sen) take the sen parameter being passed and return the longest word in the string. If

Tags: string

If there are two or more words that are the same length, return the first word from the string with that length. Ignore punctuation and assume sen will not be empty. Words may also contain numbers, for example "Hello world123 567"

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question. This is not a site where you put in your requirements and get out code. And even if it was, you didn't even specify a language ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.